# Create a list of structs the same size as another list in C

Tags: c, list

I have a list of students ordered for their registration number in C:

```
typedef struct student_type_ {                  
    int number;                              
    char name[20];                       
    char surname[20];                      
    struct stud_type_ *next_student;         
} student_type;
```

and now I want to make another list of pointers to the elements of that list, that orders it alphabetically considering the name.

```
typedef struct sort_list_ {
    struct student_type_ *student_data;
    struct sort_list *next_student;
} sort_list;
```

Therefore I thought on first creating a new sort_list with the same size as student_type, but I don't get it right... is there a simple and elegant way to do this in C?

Comment: Instead of having two different structures, you could have another `next` pointer in the `student_type_` structure, like `struct student_type_ *sorted_next;` Then you can have two lists with the exact same data, one sorted (however you want) and one unsorted.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg **same data** and **same size** are 2 totally different concepts

Comment: Also, what problem do you have with the code you have (but don't show)? The second structure would work equally fine as the proposal in my previous comment. And when you say "size" I assume you mean that you want to create a sorted list of the `sort_list_` structure with the same number of entries as the unsorted of `student_type_` structures?

Comment: Not a bad idea, but I need to create a completely new list with the exact same size.

Comment: Yes, that's it. I want to create a sorted list of the sort_list_ structure with the same number of entries as the unsorted of student_type_ structures. I don't show my code because it's too long and it doesn't work, I'm looking for a workaround to my long buggy code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a general design rule, always separate the **data** from the **presentation** of data. This will make your code cleaner and more elegant.

My suggestion: Make a `student_data` structure which contains only the student information. Then create two separate lists - one to sort by registration number and another to sort by name.

```
typedef struct student_data_ {                  
    int number;
    char name[20];
    char surname[20];
} student_data;

typedef struct sorted_student_list_ {
    struct student_data_ *student;
    struct sorted_student_list_ *next;
} sorted_student_list;

...

sorted_student_list sorted_students_by_reg_number;
sorted_student_list sorted_students_by_name;
```